# How to pass parameter to TargetedTriggerAction

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, attachedbehaviors

I've got this goto functionality in my DataGrid. This functionality I would like to keep out of my ViewModel and out of code-behind, so the following attachment could be perfect, however...

The user enters a line(item) number then when the user clicks the GotoButton it brings the item into view.

```
<Grid>
    <TextBox x:Name="GotoTextbox"  Text="{Binding GotoLineNumber, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    <Button Name="GotoButton" >
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                <helpers:TargetedTriggerActionGotoButton TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=GenericDataGrid}"  />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

Here is the TargetedTriggerAction class.

```
public class TargetedTriggerActionGotoButton : TargetedTriggerAction<DataGrid>
{
    protected override void Invoke(object parameter)
    {
        this.Target.SelectedGridItem = GotoLineNumber - 1;
        this.Target.SelectedGridIndex = GotoLineNumber.GetValueOrDefault() - 1;
    }
}
```

I would like to somehow pass the text in from GotoTextbox, is there some binding I can do?. How could I achieve this?

Comment: Don't know if this is solved or not but could you not add a property like `object Parameter {get; set;}` and then use it in your `Invoke`?

Comment: @XAMlMAX it's not solved yet, can you expand this in an answer, including how do you add a parameter in XAML.

Comment: Nevermind sorted, add in your answer as it spot on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we spoke in comments
to allow parameters to be passed in, one should implement additional property in your `TargetedTriggerAction`

```
public class TargetedTriggerActionGotoButton : TargetedTriggerAction<DataGrid>
{
    protected override void Invoke()
    {
        this.Target.SelectedGridItem = GotoLineNumber - 1;
        this.Target.SelectedGridIndex = GotoLineNumber.GetValueOrDefault() - 1;
    }
    //property used as parameter
    public object Parameter {get;set;}
}
```

and then in your `xaml`

```
<Grid>
<TextBox x:Name="GotoTextbox"  Text="{Binding GotoLineNumber, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
<Button Name="GotoButton" >
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
            <helpers:TargetedTriggerActionGotoButton TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=GenericDataGrid}" Parameter="{Binding ElementName="/*desiredName*/",Path="/*neededValue*/"}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>
```